# How are snowboard superpipe results calculated?

Tags: scoring, snowboarding, x-games

While watching the Winter X-Games during snowboard superpipe, there was a scoring mechanism that wasn't clear to me. Looking into it, Shaun White had [won the event six years in-a-row](http://xgames.espn.go.com/snowboarding/article/8870328/x-games-aspen-shaun-white-wins-men-snowboard-superpipe-final), and had a [perfect score of 100.00](http://espn.go.com/action/xgames/winter/2012/results?eventId=1012) in 2012.

From what I had gathered, scoring seems to depend on difficulty of tricks, speed, height of jumps, and execution (landing tricks cleanly, etc.) among a few things. Outside of the occasional judge/commentator expressing how one can improve his next run, not much was elaborated on the scoring mechanism.

**How are snowboard superpipe results calculated?**

Extra: Do these calculations apply to other Winter X-Games events?

Answer (score -1):

This is from the world snowboarding tour website. http://www.worldsnowboardtour.com/judging-sls/

> The Snowboarding Live Scoring System, or SLS, is a  judging system
>   that has evolved over the past 10 years. It was launched successfully
>   during the TTR 6Star Arctic Challenge Slopestyle, held in Oslo in
>   2010, and the first Halfpipe, at the 5Star BGOS in New Zealand in
>   2010. The SLS system has a focus on individual tricks combined with overall impression. There are dedicated Trick judges and OI (Overall
>   Impression) judges. The combined result of Trick and OI scores gives:
>   a detailed overview of a rider’s performance per Trick, their overall
>   run impact. the effect it has on the final position in the event. The
>   SLS system has a transparent scoring path showing how the run result
>   was achieved, a result that can be compared trick by trick, from run
>   to run. Each TRICK is judged by teams of two. They focus on just one
>   feature in the Slopestyle course, and one hit in the Halfpipe. Judges
>   will concentrate their judging values on Amplitude, Difficulty and
>   Execution. Each OI judge  focuses on the overall impact of the run
>   over the entire course. Judges will concentrate their judging values
>   on Variation, Style and Combinations.
>
> In Halfpipe, the SLS system allocates two dedicated judges per hit.
>   Two judges score each specific hit. All hits have the same value
>   assigned. Based on the maximum value of the hit, a trick score is
>   calculated. Only the 4 best individual Trick scores are kept and then
>   added up for a Total Trick score. For the Flow Score, two additional
>   judges are dedicated to focusing solely on the usage and composition
>   of the halfpipe run. Flow judges will take into account all tricks
>   beyond the 4 top scoring hits that are scored by the judges as well as
>   any insecurity including falls. The two OI scores are averaged thus :
>   Total Trick + Total OI score results makes a Run score, which defines
>   a rider’s final position in the event ranking. Trick and OI judges
>   will score on a 0 -100 scale. The Run Score is the sum of the total
>   Trick and OI score combined and will be communicated as a common 0 –
>   100 points value.